# boundingrect not working for a contour in opencv c++

Tags: opencv, visual-c++, contour

{

```
 #include<opencv2\opencv.hpp>
 #include<iostream>
 #include<conio.h>

 using namespace std;
 using namespace cv;

 int main()
{
int a = 0;

Mat frame, diffimage,back,frame_gray;
VideoCapture cap("D:\\elance\\check\\Sent3.avi");
vector<vector<Point>> contours;
BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 bg;
vector<int> params;
params.push_back(CV_IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION);
params.push_back(9);

for (int i = 0; i < 200;i++)
{
    cap >> frame;
    if (frame.empty())
        break;
    bg(frame,back);
}

bg.getBackgroundImage(back);
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES,0);
cvtColor(back, back, CV_BGR2GRAY);
//for (int f = 0; f < 20;f++)
while (1)
{
    a = a + 1;
    cout << "Frame no : " << a<<endl;
    cap >> frame;
    if (frame.empty())
        break;
    cvtColor(frame, frame_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    absdiff(frame_gray, back, diffimage);
    threshold(diffimage, diffimage, 10, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        cv::erode(diffimage, diffimage, cv::Mat());
        cv::dilate(diffimage, diffimage, cv::Mat());
    }
    findContours(diffimage, contours, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
    cout << "Contour Size : " << contours.size()<<endl;
    vector<Rect> boundRect(contours.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {
        drawContours(frame, contours, i, cv::Scalar(0, 255, 255), 1);
        Mat smoothCont;
        smoothCont = cv::Mat(contours[i]);
        cout << smoothCont.rows << "\t" << smoothCont.cols <<"\t"<<smoothCont.depth()<< endl << endl;
        if (smoothCont.rows > 0 && smoothCont.rows < 10000)
            boundRect[i] = boundingRect(Mat(contours[i]));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
        rectangle(frame, boundRect[i], Scalar(0, 255, 255), 1, 8, 0);
    imshow("Diff", diffimage);
    imshow("frame", frame);
    imwrite("D:\\test.jpg", frame, params);
    waitKey(30);
    break;
}
```

}

This code basically takes the contours and results are the rectangles on the contours. But  only one is bounded by the box and other contour is is still not bounded box.

Can anyone help in this matter ?

Comment: From Mat SmoothCont i was trying to find number of row and column of the contour vector and some contours were of negative column can you explain that ?

Comment: better use contours[i].size() anyway.

Comment: but still this doesnt solve my problem

Comment: this code should work for multiple bounding boxes right

Answer (score 0):

Maybe "if (smoothCont.rows > 0 && smoothCont.rows < 10000)" filtered them out?

Comment: I have tried this method but then also it isn't working

Comment: as the bounding rectangle returned by the function is giving negative values of rectangle coordinates

Comment: I remember boundingRect takes vector<Point>, not Mat. Is there a specific reason you are converting it to Mat?

Comment: I have used directly contours in the program still it is giving negative valuse