# negative values of rectange in bounding box in opencv c++

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-c++, bounding-box

```
    vector<vector<Point>> contours;
    findContours(diffimage, contours, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
    cout << "Contour Size : " << contours.size()<<endl;
    vector<Rect> boundRect(contours.size());
    for (int j = 0; j < contours.size(); j++)
    {
        cout << "Contour[i] Size : " << contours[j].size() << endl;
        boundRect[j] = boundingRect(contours[j]);
        cout << "Rectangle :" << boundRect[j].x << '\t' << boundRect[j].y << '\t' <<          boundRect[j].width << '\t' << boundRect[j].height << endl;
    }
```

I have detected two contours in the image.
When i run the {bounding Rectangle} on it.

One of the contour is correctly detected with positive set of values of the rectangle dimensions.

The other one is giving negative set of large values of the rectangle dimensions.

Can anyone tell me the reason and the possible solution?

Comment: Can you draw each single contour in an empty image (or a clone of original image), and `waitKey(0)` after `imshow` within that loop right after the `cout`? Are there any strange/unexpected/empty contours for your negative valued rects?

Comment: i have used drawContour in which they are showing two contour in the image clearly and both contours are normal

Comment: can you tell which of those two contours gives you negative rect values? if not, please dont draw them at once, but with a pause on a blank image.

Comment: second contour in the image

Comment: can you `cout` each single point of that contour`? can you please add all those coordinates and the result of `cout << boundingRect(contours[j]) << std::endl;` for that contour to your question?

Comment: and can you please add the line of code where you declared your `contours` variable? Since you only posted a fragment of your code, can you give information whether there done anything with that variable in between `declaration, findContours and the loop`?

Comment: and in between i am not doing anything

Comment: contour[0] has rect x = 364 y = 433 width = 25 height =15

Comment: contour[1] has rect x = -1414812757 y= -1414812757 width = -812603567 height = -18772448824

Comment: and frame size is 640x480

Comment: can you add all points of `contour[1]`? e.g. `for(int k=0; k<contours[1].size(); ++k){cout << contours[1][k] << std::endl;}` just copy/paste result from terminal.

Comment: just interested: since you used loop variable `j`, is there any "outer loop" in your full code where `contours` isnt resetted/emptied or something? I'm not sure how `findContours` handles cases where output vector isnt empty.

Comment: no sir i have used different variable for different loops

Comment: Can you add the points of that contour? Not sure if there is any other possibility to find the error.

Comment: if you are still using full code from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25289008/boundingrect-not-working-for-a-contour-in-opencv-c

Can you please change `vector<Rect> boundRect(contours.size());` to `vector<Rect> boundRect;` and `.push_back` the rects after computation? e.g. `boundRect.push_back(boundingRect(contours[j]));`